# Is AbstractAppEngineAuthorizationCodeServlet supported on Appengine Flexible Environment?

Tags: jsp, google-app-engine, authentication, app-engine-flexible

I was wondering if AbstractAppEngineAuthorizationCodeCallbackServlet from com.google.api-client is supported by AppEngine flexible environment.

I'm working on the migration from the deprecated environment (vm:true) to the latest version of Flexible Environment (env:flex).

When accessing one of my servlets which extends from AbstractAppEngineAuthorizationCodeServlet the flow works perfectly and the redirect is done to other servlet, which extends from AbstractAppEngineAuthorizationCodeCallbackServlet. Now, when it tries to run:

```
TokenResponse response = flow.newTokenRequest(code).setRedirectUri(redirectUri).execute();
```

(Line inside the doGet from AbstractAuthorizationCodeCallbackServlet class)

it retuns an:

```
com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException: Can't make API call urlfetch.Fetch in a thread that is neither the original request thread nor a thread created by ThreadManager
```

---

**UPDATE**

I could check on Cloud Console that my instance is indeed running on Flexible.

Comment: Per https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/apphosting/api/ApiProxy, it seems to be an App Engin estandard env API. This is probably why you get the error. In fact, I am familiar with the the error message, which is a restriction on the standard env: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/runtime-java8#threads. I think your code is still using the App Engine standard API somehow.

Comment: @ChanseokOh I agree with you according to the documentations mentioned above. But is there some how to check what is the current environment of a service? Because according to the Migration documentation, besides other changes required by the new environment, what defines which environment I'm using is the env:flex on app.yaml.

Comment: one way is to go to console.cloud.google.com, select your project > App Engine > Versions. The "Environment" column will display "flexible" for "env: flex". Based on what you said, I bet you are on the flexible environment.

Comment: Yeah, it is. But I was checking the versions before and all of it are showing "flexible". Seems like the parameter "VM: true" actually are already setting up the flexible environment. I see now that I just moved from the old to the last version of flexible instead of migrate from standard to flexible... But still don't know what is going on with the lib.

Comment: "vm: true" and "env: flexible" were certainly different runtime environments. The environment designed by "vm: true" was historically called "Managed VMs", which is defunct both as a valid runtime and in terms of branding: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/upgrading Managed VMs was sort of similar to the flexible env, but they weren't same.

Comment: Were you on the flex "compat" environment (a special env provided for customers who wanted to have an interim migration step going from standard to flexible) by any chance? I still think the root problem is that someone is calling a standard env API, which doesn't exist at all on flex.

Comment: I don't think so. I read about a form that i had to fill up in order to be on "compat" environment and I didn't. I found out an workaround by implementing the Auth flow without using libs, but I'll keep looking for a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out what was wrong with the lib usage

On creation of GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow object, I was passing a GoogleClientSecrets:

```
Builder(HttpTransport transport, JsonFactory jsonFactory, GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets, Collection<String> scopes)
```

For some reason, passing the id and secret as Strings (using the other constructor of Builder), it works.

```
GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(HttpTransport, JsonFactory, String, String, Collection<String> scopes)
```

Not sure about the reason, though.

------------------------------------- EDIT -----------------------------------

I just saw here that I made another change besides NOT use GoogleClientSecrets object.

```
private static final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
private static final UrlFetchTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new UrlFetchTransport();
```

Using UrlFetchTransport instead of NetHttpTransport was the truly reason of stacktrace shown.

Comment: Interesting. Filed a bug: https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client/issues/1105

Comment: @ChanseokOh please, check my update. I was mistaken.

Comment: Yeah, URL fetch is a standard environment thing: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/migrating#url_fetch You shouldn't use it on the flexible environment.

Comment: If `GoogleClientSecrets` is not the cause, I suggest to remove it from your accepted answer, to provide accurate info to others with similar problems. BTW, I filed a bug to update the std-to-flex migration doc.